# Can DTD entities be used to define children of an element?

Tags: entity, element, dtd, reusability

When defining an element in DTD is it possible to use an entity to replace probable duplication of children elements?

For example instead of defining the following elements:

```
<!ELEMENT bear (weight, height, power)>
<!ELEMENT human (weight, height, power)>
```

Could I just replace the definition of the children with a defined entity like that:

```
<!ELEMENT bear &stats;>
<!ELEMENT human &stats;>
<!ENTITY stats "(weight, height, power)">
```

If not, what is the way to avoid duplication (in DTDs not Schemas)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeking help from a web specialist I found that the example in the question is ALMOST right. Entities can be used in order to define elements and avoid duplication in a slightly different way (see example below).

```
<!ENTITY % stats "(weight, height, power)">
<!ELEMENT bear %stats;>
<!ELEMENT human %stats;>
```